# Is there a Flutter calendar widget that allows importing .ics files?

Tags: flutter

I have been looking at Flutter calendar widgets for an app I want to build, however it would be convenient if I could import ics files into it and I dont know if there are any that would be suitable. Also, is the only alternative to parse ics files and add them to the calendar?

I havent done anything as I'm uncertain which Calendar widget to use

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package called as icalendar_parser to read all the events/parse the .ics file
https://pub.dev/packages/icalendar_parser

to display the events in calendar there is one great package which comes with lot of customisation called as sync fusion_flutter_calendar
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar